# How to manage installations with HDD+SSD ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I am thinking of buying a laptop with 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD and I want to install Ubuntu. I want the OS to be on the SSD and installed apps and all other files on HDD. Is that possible? How can I control where Ubuntu installs apps? I am very new to Linux, so sorry if it's s stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the OS to be on the SSD and installed apps and all other files on HDD. Is that possible?

Yes, but there should almost be no need for that.

The directory to install 3rd party software is `/opt/` so you mount the HDD as `/opt/`. In the same procedure you can set your personal directories to `/opt/Desktop` etc. (see `~./config/users-dirs.dirs` for the config for this).

> How can I control where Ubuntu installs apps?

Ubuntu itself will install its software in the normal directories so that will be on the ssd. I have never needed more than 30Gb though. The more important software like mysql, apache will have a config setup where you tell it to use a specific location for the persnonal files so you can direct that to `/opt/`.

It is the personal data that will eat up diskspace and the location used for that you can always control. In the worst case there is no config and you need to create a symlink (ie. shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible
[This link](https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/) shows you how to achieve it.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the question. If (when installing Ubuntu) I put root and swap on the SSD and home on the HDD, where will the package installer install apps: on the SSD or HDD?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install apps on the SDD too, besides the OS. That way you to take adventage of it, with very quick starups.
And all your personal files on the HDD, because they don't need high speeds to be loaded.

For that, just select the HDD to be mounted at `/home`, and the SDD at `/` on the installation process.

Comment: Will 128GB be enough? I am planning to use the laptop primarily for programming (no gaming) and want to install Android Studio, eclipse, and other coding environments...

Comment: even 30Gb is more than enough

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to make a new partition which is mountable by your linux distro. Then you can see the path of your disk in "Disk Usage Analyzer" and should be ok